# How to Copy Cells on Excel With All Atribute With VBA Function as Excel Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy 1 cell on Excel with attributes (color, background color, border) to Active Cell with Excel Formula. So, I can write

```
=CopyCell(B2)
```

and the Active Cell copying B2 with all atributes. Can you help me?

I just succeed to copy one cell to another using button onClick with calling this procedure

```
Public Function CopyOnlyFormatConditionColor(ByVal Source As String, ByVal Destination As String)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Source).Copy Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Destination)
End Function
```

Thanks to any help

Answer (score 0):

I have not solved this; but this is what I have so far. [The stack overflow answering guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ask to share what I have discovered, in case it helps the next person...

```vb
    Public Function CopyColor(Target As Range)
    
    Dim iCol%, iCol2%
    Dim iRow&, iRow2&
    Dim sSheet$, sSheet2$
    Dim WS As Worksheet, WS2 As Worksheet
    
    Set WS = Target.Worksheet
    sSheet = WS.Name
    iRow = Target.Row
    iCol = Target.Column
    
    Set WS2 = Application.ActiveCell.Worksheet
    sSheet2 = WS2.Name
    iRow2 = Application.ActiveCell.Row
    iCol2 = Application.ActiveCell.Column
    
    WS.Cells(iRow, iCol).Copy
    WS2.Cells(iRow2, iCol2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    WS2.Cells(iRow2, iCol2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    End Function
```